# SWIFT: UIRefreshControl() and tableView.reload() NOT working

Tags: json, iphone, swift, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

I'm currently pulling JSON data from the booking service I use. I have it displaying nicely in ViewController but I can't seem to get UIRefreshControl() to work and refresh the table with the JSON data.

Here is my code to GET the JSON data.

```
let urlToRequest = "https://api.bookeo.com/v2/availability/slots?secretKey=<secretKey>&type=fixed&apiKey=<apiKey>&startTime=2018-02-03T09:30:00-05:00&endTime=2018-02-03T22:00:00-05:00"
    func dataRequest() {
        let url4 = URL(string: urlToRequest)!
        let session4 = URLSession.shared
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url4)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData
        let paramString = "data=Hello"
        request.httpBody = paramString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        let task = session4.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let _: Data = data, let _: URLResponse = response, error == nil else {
                print("*****error")
                return
            }
            let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
            print("*****This is the data 4: \(String(describing: dataString))") //JSONSerialization
        }
        task.resume()
        DispatchQueue.main.async{
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    dataRequest()


   if let url = URL(string: urlToRequest) {

        if let data = try? String(contentsOf: url) {
            let json = JSON(parseJSON: data)

            if json["info"]["totalItems"].intValue == 50 {
                parse(json: json)
                return
            }
        }
    }

    showError()
}
```

Here is the bit I have for Parsing the JSON.

```
func parse(json: JSON) {
    for result in json["data"].arrayValue {
        let productId = result["productId"].stringValue
        let startTime = result["startTime"].stringValue
        let numSeatsAvailable = result["numSeatsAvailable"].stringValue
        let obj = ["productId": productId, "startTime": startTime, "numSeatsAvailable": numSeatsAvailable]
        petitions.append(obj)

    }
    //tableView.reloadData()
    DispatchQueue.main.async{
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

}
```

Here is my code for the UIRefreshControl()

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {
var petitions = [[String: String]]()
var refresh = UIRefreshControl()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    refresh = UIRefreshControl()
    refresh.tintColor = UIColor.darkGray
    refresh.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.refreshData), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
    tableView.refreshControl = refresh
    tableView.addSubview(refresh)
```

And then the function for Refreshing...

```
@objc func refreshData() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async{
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    refresh.endRefreshing()
}
```

Please help me find out what I"m doing wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Matt, I copied the code `DispatchQueue.main.async` from another website trying to solve this same problem. To be honest, I'm not sure what it's for.

Comment: When I open the app and try to refresh the table, nothing happens. It just stays the same even though I change the incoming data from my end.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. When I open the app on my iPhone, I swipe down and get the "Loading" symbol (telling me that the screen is refreshing). But nothing happens.

Comment: Also you do realize, don't you, that in `func dataRequest` you are reloading the table _before_ the new data has arrived?

Comment: Okay. That is what I need some assistance with. Do you have any idea of what I would need to add to `obj func refreshData()` to make it work?

Comment: Also, I just fixed the reload table inside of `func dataRequest`. I had copied that code from another forum.

Comment: You say "Please help me find out what I"m doing wrong". I suggest you use the debugger. You have a wonderful debugger! Put breakpoints in all the key places and let your code step through so you can see in what order things are happening and what the value of your variables is at each point.

Comment: Here is a link to the rest of my code including the table data - [https://docs.google.com/document/d/1C7oeLkKzRht985xUZj9jhV2quPNEuY7_KmNnPIqIuTM/edit?usp=sharing]